# Что такое lparam в WM_SETCURSOR?

Tags: c++, winapi

Что такое lparam в WM_SETCURSOR в моём случае lparam равен 0x2000001, а что это такое и существует какой то макрос для 0x2000001?

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETCURSOR, (WPARAM)hWnd, 0x2000001);
```

Comment: http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/winapi/curs/r.php?33

Comment: что именно такое 0x2000001 есть макрос на это?

Comment: Ну, похоже, loWord - `#define HTCLIENT  1`; подозреваю также, что hiWord - `#define WM_MOUSEMOVE  0x0200`.

Comment: @Harry, не могли бы вы мне подсказать как это теперь обьеденить?

    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETCURSOR, (WPARAM)hWnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE | HTCLIENT); 

пробую так не работает получается 201

Comment: `MAKELPARAM(HTCLIENT,WM_MOUSEMOVE)`

Comment: @Harry, спасибо!